# While upgrading Web API from Visual studio 2022 Version 3.1 to Version 6.0 exception is occurred

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to upgrade .Net core Web API  application from 3.1 to 6.0 and after upgrading a exception is displayed while compiling:

> "{"StatusCode":500,"Message":"The type initializer for 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ResultOperators.Internal.TrackingExpressionNode' threw an exception."}"

[image]

Comment: Your title doesn't make sense. Di you mean _"While upgrading ASP.NET Core Web API  from 3.1 to 6.0 exception is occurred"_? Still not a great title though!

Comment: I have a suggestion that you can update all the NuGet packages to their latest .NET 6 version, it wil fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've seen this issue myself.

If it's the same thing then it's an easy fix.

Find your nuget package for entity framework core and try updating it to the latest version.  I think older versions are incompatible with .Net 6.

Looking at a scratch app I have which compiles to net 6

I can add

```
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.2" />
```

[image]

Comment: Can you suggest me the version of entity framework core for .Net 6 ?

Comment: the lastest version 7.0.0 of entity framework core  is not support to .Net standard 2.1

Comment: @kinjal 7.0.2 has a dependency on net 6.  If you tried that then are there some of it's dependencies you reference specifically?